# Prove that $\frac{\pi}{4}\le\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n+1}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, contest-math

Prove that
$$\frac{\pi}{4}\le\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n+1}\right)$$

**EDIT:** inspired by Michael Hardy's suggestion I got that

$$\arcsin \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}=\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}-\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}$$
and then
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n+1}\right)\ge\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}\right)\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{4}$$
because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}-\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}\right)=\arcsin \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Sis & Chris.

Comment: We have
\begin{align}
\arcsin \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}}{n+1}\right) & \geq \dfrac{\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}}{n+1} = \dfrac1{n+1} \cdot \dfrac1{\left(\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}\right)}\\
& \geq \dfrac1{2(n+1)^{3/2}}
\end{align}
Hence,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{2(n+1)^{3/2}}  = \dfrac{\zeta(3/2)-1}2$$
Hence, it is sufficient to prove that $$\zeta3/2) \geq 1 + \dfrac{\pi}2$$

Comment: @Marvis: a small difference there $\approx 0.041579$. On the other hand, since it's a contest math question I think there should be a trick that would give us that $\frac{\pi}{4}$ (it's more a guess).

Comment: @Marvis: thanks for your point!

Comment: I'm guessing the identity $\arcsin a + \arcsin b$ $= \arcsin\left(a\sqrt{1-b^2} + b\sqrt{1-a^2}\right)$ may be relevant.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I was trying to turn that one around (expand $\arcsin(x+y)$ into $t + u$) but it got ugly. (I tried to use $\sin(\arctan(x)) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 +1}}$ and arctan addition.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since $\arcsin x\ge \arctan x$ for $x \in [0,1]$, thus we shall have
$$\arcsin(\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n+1})\ge \arctan(\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n+1})\ge \arctan\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n}+1} $$ $$= \arctan{\sqrt{n+1}}-\arctan{\sqrt{n}}.$$

(The last equality uses $\arctan(x) - \arctan(y) = \arctan(\frac{x-y}{1 + xy})$.)

Done.

P.S.

$\sum \arcsin(\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n+1}) \ge \sum(\arctan{\sqrt{n+1}}-\arctan{\sqrt{n}}) = \pi/2-\arctan(1)=\pi/4$

Comment: @PeterTamaroff He may have a point. In the interval $\[0, 1]$, we have $\sin(\arctan(x)) \le \sin(\arcsin(x))$, since the former is $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 +1}}$, while the latter is simply $x$. Since $\sin$ is increasing on that interval, we obtain $\arctan(x) \le \arcsin(x)$. (Notice that the arguments of $\arcsin$ for all terms in our series lie in $\[0, 1]$. Thus, the inequality is valid for every term in our series.)

Comment: I'm not sure about the last part, however, since it's marred by a typo.

Comment: @Yimin Dude, several things. One: the limit of $\arctan(x)$ as x tends to infinity is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, not $\pi$. Two: fortunately, $\arctan(1)$ is $\frac{\pi}{4}$, not $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Three: your argument just stops making sense at the end.

Comment: I did not question the **first** inequality, but the last ones.

Comment: I added the last part. For each term, you may have seen that $(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})/(n+1)\le 1$, thus the inequality at beginning holds for each term.

Comment: $\arctan(x)$ isn't a linear map! It isn't so that $\arctan(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}) = \arctan(\sqrt{n+1}) - \arctan(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: @user1296727 I have seen my typo, I forgot the \frac.

Comment: Ahhh. Much better! (+1)

Comment: @user1296727 And I realized my fault of computing arctan($\infty$)... Sorry about the spams.

Comment: No, no worries. I find this really clever. (That's why I was so picky.)

Comment: Now it is clearer, thanks. There was quite a typo.

Comment: @Yimin: that's a clever solution. Thanks! (+1) (Maybe you may improve a bit your text such that the proof be clear)

Comment: +1 good job. It was clever to shift from arcsin to arctan